# How to select an element using text() in Selenium with Python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am not able to select "Event" in following code using text().

```
<a class="atg-p-8" href="https://www.abc.com">
            <span class="atg-mr-12">... </span>
              " Event
               "
</a>
```

This is the Xpath that I'm using:- ( `.//a/span[text() ='Event']` )

Comment: The span text is `... ` - "Event" is outside the span. You may also need to use a contains or partial link text function if the spacing between the word and the quotation marks is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

```
//a[text()[contains(.,'Event')]]
```

the tag have two text node so you have to use the above locator , this checks if any text node of a has Event in it

you can also use:

```
//a[contains(string(),'Event')]
```

This will convert all text node to string and then search event in it

Answer (score 1):

You can try as following

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Event')]")
```